# DetachedInstanceError after rollback

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, rollback

I am using sqlalchemy v0.9.9 (and I can't do an update because of some problems I would get) and python 2.7.13.

I do have a session and when I try to do two rollbacks like

```
person = Person()
person.forename = "Katharine"
person.surname = "Hepburn"
session.add(person)
session.begin_nested()
person.forename = "Audrey"
session.rollback()
session.rollback()

print person
```

I get the following statement:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Personen at 0x805b83ef0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

And I understand, that one maybe shouldn't work with objects one doesn't want to add to a session, but when I explicitly ask for an attribute of the object (and not the object itself, because that wouldn't work), like this:

```
person = Person()
person.forename = "Katharine"
person.surname = "Hepburn"
session.add(person)
session.begin_nested()
person.forename = "Audrey"
session.rollback()
person.forename
session.rollback()
```

then I don't get any exception. So I do have to questions:

1. What's the purpose of this behavior
2. How could I use the person object after the second rollback without adding an useless expression like `person.forename` between the rollbacks?

Thanks for your time!

---

My whole code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from orm_model import UpdateableViewModelBase
from orm_model import OrmModelBase
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String

class Person(OrmModelBase, UpdateableViewModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    person_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    forename = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, person_id):
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.forename = ''
        self.surename = ''

def connect():
    engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    return engine, session

def main():
    engine, session = connect()
    person = Person(person_id=50000)
    person.forename = "Katharine"
    person.surname = "Hepburn"
    session.add(person)
    session.begin_nested()
    person.forename = "Audrey"
    session.rollback()
    person.forename
    session.rollback()
```

This code was just to make sure that this a "problem" with the behavoir after the second rollback so I wrote it the easiest way.

Comment: why do you need two consecutive rollbacks?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are those the exact steps?

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov: In my real code they are not direktly consecutive but I get the same `DetachedInstanceError` so I made this little pseudocode to make sure that it's the behavoir of something other than my code.

Comment: The thing is: there's probably something that expunges (detaches) in between. A call to `session.expunge_all()` or some such.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä: I thought about it too, but I never use expunge_all() or some thing like that. I added my whole testcode to my question.